# Change imagen automatic with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page output changes depending on the images that are in it that are alarms , I use the JavaScript function:

```
document.getElementById ( 'ID' ) src = "img / img_1.png .";
```

but sometimes the image does not change visually but the correct variable change is made in the DOM tell me that this is because there is no compatibility with some browsers , is there some other more recent equivalent function that can fill this role?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way ..

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("ID");
image.src = "img/img_1.png";
```

be sure about the path

or

```
image.src = "./img/img_1.png";
```

in jquery you can

```
 $("#ID").attr("src","img/img_1.png");
```